# How to enable do not display lock screen in Windows with powershell cmd?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to enable the do not display lock screen in Windows server. instead of setting it up on Group policy by navigating to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > Do not display lock screen

i have tried running below

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization" -Name "NoLockScreen" -Value 0
```

but it didn't work. how to enable do not display lock screen in windows with Powershell cmd?

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: The `Personalization` key doesn't exist by default, so the command will usually fail with an error like "Cannot find path". Try running `Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization"`, and add the results to your question.

Comment: [`New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization" -Name "NoLockScreen" -Value 0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.4)